# Clustering a list with nearest values without sorting

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, lambda

I have a list like this

```
tst = [1,3,4,6,8,22,24,25,26,67,68,70,72,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,5,6,36,38,36,31]
```

I want to group the elements from above list into separate groups/lists based on the difference between the consecutive elements in the list (differing by 1 or 2 or 3).
I have tried following code

```
def slice_when(predicate, iterable):
    i, x, size = 0, 0, len(iterable)
    while i < size-1:
        if predicate(iterable[i], iterable[i+1]):
           yield iterable[x:i+1]
           x = i + 1
        i += 1
    yield iterable[x:size]

tst = [1,3,4,6,8,22,24,25,26,67,68,70,72,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,5,6,36,38,36,31]
slices = slice_when(lambda x,y: (y - x > 2), tst)
whola=(list(slices))
```

I got this results

```
[[1, 3, 4, 6, 8], [22, 24, 25, 26], [67, 68, 70, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 5, 6], [36, 38, 36, 31]]
```

In 3rd list it doesn't separate the sequence of zeros into another list. Any kind of help highly appreciate. Thank you

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. Currently it's not reproducible. [mre]

Comment: Yeah, Sure. Sorry for that. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want?

```
tst = [1,3,4,6,8,22,24,25,26,67,68,70,72,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,5,6,36,38,36,31]
slices = slice_when(lambda x,y: (abs(y - x) > 2), tst) # Use abs!
whola=(list(slices))
print(whola)
```